# Python hydra sweeper parameter treated as string

Tags: fb-hydra

I want to do a [hydra](https://hydra.cc/) sweep, where I sweep over possible Python functions to instantiate with `hydra.utils.call` (or `hydra.utils.instantiate`). When I do the sweep however, `hydra` thinks the parameters are a string, instead of an object to be instantiated within the Python main script.

I have a directory `project_root` with 6 files:

```
├── config
│   ├── main.yaml
│   └── optimization
│       ├── main.yaml
│       └── utility_function
│           ├── eig.yaml
│           └── ucb.yaml
├── main.py
└── utils.py
```

The main config file `project_root/config/main.yaml` has:

```
defaults:
  - _self_
  - optimization: main

hydra:
  sweeper:
    params:
      optimization.utility_function: eig, ucb
```

The `optimization` default comes from `project_root/optimization/main.yaml`:

```
defaults:
  - utility_function: eig
```

In the sweeper, `eig` and `ucb` point to Python functions, for example `project_root/config/optimization/utility_function/eig.yaml` is:

```
_target_: utils.eig
_partial_: true
```

And similarly, `project_root/config/optimization/utility_function/ucb.yaml` is:

```
_target_: utils.ucb
_partial_: true
```

The `_partial_` key is set based on what I saw in [the documentation](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/instantiate_objects/overview/), since I want to pass values to the instantiated Python functions in the real project I'm working on.

Both of the above refer to Python functions called `eig` and `ucb` in `project_root/utils.py`:

```
def eig(x):
    return "This is the EIG function"


def ucb(x):
    return "This is the UCB function"
```

All of this is brought together in `project_root/main.py`:

```
import hydra
from hydra.utils import call


def train_debug(cfg):
    print(f"cfg.optimization.utility={cfg.optimization.utility_function}.")
    print(f"type(cfg.optimization.utility)={type(cfg.optimization.utility_function)}.")
    print(call(cfg.optimization.utility_function)("dummyarg"))


@hydra.main(config_path="config", config_name="main", version_base="1.3")
def run(cfg):
    train_debug(cfg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

When I want to do the sweep with:

```
python main.py -m
```

I get the following output:

```
[2023-06-21 14:58:04,932][HYDRA] Launching 2 jobs locally
[2023-06-21 14:58:04,932][HYDRA]    #0 : optimization.utility_function=eig
cfg.optimization.utility=eig.
type(cfg.optimization.utility)=<class 'str'>.
[2023-06-21 14:58:05,000][HYDRA]    #1 : optimization.utility_function=ucb
cfg.optimization.utility=ucb.
type(cfg.optimization.utility)=<class 'str'>.
Error executing job with overrides: ['optimization.utility_function=eig']
Cannot instantiate config of type str.
Top level config must be an OmegaConf DictConfig/ListConfig object,
a plain dict/list, or a Structured Config class or instance.
```

Things do work when I just run:

```
python main.py
```

And I get the output:

```
cfg.optimization.utility={'_target_': 'utils.eig', '_partial_': True}.
type(cfg.optimization.utility)=<class 'omegaconf.dictconfig.DictConfig'>.
This is the EIG function
```

Any ideas on what I should do to be able to do a sweep over the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the key `optimization.utility_function` is getting the string values `eig` and `ucb` in each of the runs.

```yaml
hydra:
  sweeper:
    params:
      optimization.utility_function: eig, ucb
```

The proper way to override nested config groups is with a slash as separator.
Also, before you use the sweeper config, I suggest you try in the command line.
Something like:

```
$ python main.py -m optimization/utility_function=eig,ucb
```